# C programming - tcp socket remote port retrieving

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a tcp connected socket handle, created through an accept. Only the handle, not other structs. How can I retrieve its REMOTE port from the handle? I mean, the tcp source port of the connection  Remote Client ---> Me

Comment: Yes, the other structs.  2nd argument, sockaddr_in.sin_port.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining the TCP port number to which client got bound.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347636/determining-the-tcp-port-number-to-which-client-got-bound)

Answer (score 8):

The [`getpeername`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/getpeername.html) function gets information about the remote side, including the port number; [`getsockname`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/getsockname.html) does the same for the local side of the connection.